# What is the best way to do C-struct in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Currently I use data `fields` to mimic a C-struct. But I found that unlike the domain-driven way of programming like `object.property`, in haskell the property names are all dumped into the module namespace. This creates some problems when I have more than one such struct. For example, what if I have two data types:

```
data Person = Person { name :: Text, address :: Text }
data Dog = Dog { name :: Text, breed :: Text }
```

then GHC will complain: `Multiple declarations of ‘name’`. Thus I have to name the "properties" with prefixes:

```
data Person = Person { getPersonName :: Text, getPersonAddress :: Text }
data Dog = Dog { getDogName :: Text, getDogBreed :: Text }
```

is this necessary? Or am I using the wrong way to define a struct?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use the `-XDisambiguateRecordFields` extension. It allows exactly this: using the same name of record label in multiple data declaration.

However, you should think about whether this is really needed. If two data types contain the same conceptual thing, would it perhaps be better to remove that field from both types and use it in a common wrapper instead?

```
data Person' = Person { address :: Text }
data Dog' = Dog { breed :: Text }

data Named b = Named { name :: Text, being :: b }

type Person = Named Person'
type Dog = Named Dog'
```